# array push replacing or erasing the existing values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, array-push

I have a problem with my code here... Basically, I have a page (edit_patient.php) which is receiving (GET) a number from another page (new_patient.php)... On the edit_patient.php page I want to either edit or add new information to what's already posted from new_patient.php...
The problem is, that I have an array and I want to push the old array to add new values to this existing array...
When I post, the information gets either replaced or erased...
Here are my codes:

```
<?php
// Update the database with new information from form;
if (isset($_POST['dossier'])){
    $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['thisID']);
    if (!empty($_POST['medication'])|| ($_POST['posology'])) {
        $thisArraysql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT medication, posology FROM patient WHERE dossier='$thisID' LIMIT 1");
        $medArray_count = mysqli_num_rows($thisArraysql);
        if ($medArray_count > 0) {      
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($thisArraysql)) {
                    $old_medication = $row["medication"];
                    $old_posology = $row["posology"];
            }
            $medication .= array_push($old_medication, implode('-', $_POST['medication']));
            $posology .= array_push($old_posology, implode('-',$_POST['posology']));
        } else {
            $medication = implode('-', $_POST['medication']);
            $posology = implode('-', $_POST['posology']);
        }
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE patient  SET medication = '$medication', posology = '$posology' WHERE dossier = '$pid'";

    if (!mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
        } else {
            header("location: patients_list.php");  
        }
    exit();
}
// Get pid from new_patient.php; Select the patient from database;
if (isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE dossier='$targetID' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    $patientCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($patientCount > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $dossier = $row["dossier"];
            $medication = explode('-',$row['medication']);
                $medication_count = count($medication);
                $medication_count_added = $medication_count+1;
            $posology = explode('-',$row['posology']);
        }
    } else {

    echo "This patient does not exist!";

    exit();
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<!-- this scripts adds more fields to the array -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs          = 19-"<?php echo $medication_count; ?>"; //maximum input boxes allowed
var CurrentSituation    = $("#CurrentSituation"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton              = $("#AddMoreFieldBox"); //Add button ID

var x = CurrentSituation.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount="<?php echo $medication_count_added; ?>"+1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(CurrentSituation).append('<tr class="field_added"><td><input type="text" name="medication['+ FieldCount +']" id="medication['+ FieldCount +']" size="40" /></td><td><input type="number" name="posology['+ FieldCount +']" id="posology['+ FieldCount +']" min="1" max="100000" /></td><td><a href="#" class="removeclass">Effacer</a></td></tr>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove(); //remove text box
                x--; //decrement textbox
        }
return false;
}) 

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit_patient.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Dossier Number: <input type="number" id="dossier" name="dossier" readonly value="<?php echo $dossier; ?>" />
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Medication(s)</td>
            <td colspan="2">Posology(ies)</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        echo "<tr><td><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\">";
        foreach ($medication as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>$value</td></tr>";            
        }
        echo "</table></td><td><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\">";                   
        foreach ($posology as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table></td></tr>";                  
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="medication[<?php echo $medication_count_added; ?>]" id="medication[<?php echo $medication_count_added; ?>]" size="40" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="posology[<?php echo $medication_count_added; ?>]" id="posology[<?php echo $medication_count_added; ?>]" min="1" max="100000" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for your help, time, comprehension and dedication!!

EDIT:

I replaced the code for the array as such:

```
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($thisArraysql) < 0) {
    $medication = implode('-', $_POST['medication']);
    $posology = implode('-', $_POST['posology']);
} else {
    $medication = array();
    $posology = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($thisArraysql)) {
      $medication[] = $row["medication"];
      $posology[] = $row["posology"];
    }
     foreach ($_POST['medication'] as $key => $value) {
        $medication[$key] = $value;
    }
    foreach ($_POST['posology'] as $key => $value) {
        $posology[$key] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

But I am still getting the same error... the array gets replaced by the word Array...

EDIT 2

I created a new patient (new_patient.php) and added some info in the array. Once in the edit_patient.php (this page that I have problems with), I did a var_dump and this is what I get:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Med 1-Med 2-Med 3-Med 4-' (length=24)
array (size=1)
  0 => string '25-30-50-5-' (length=11)
```

Now, if I update the array I get this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Array' (length=5)
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Array' (length=5)
```

Comment: You're replacing the array value with this, not adding to it. Build your values form MySQL into an array first, then push that whole array into the $_POST value.

Comment: Hmm should I explode from sql then use array_push($medication, implode....) ??

Comment: you don't have to explode anything. You are already getting an array back from the db. Build an array, add the $_POST['medications'] values to that array, then overwrite the $_POST['medications'] with the new array.

Comment: Ok I think I get it... I'll try it out theb I'll keep you posted!!! Thank you so much VikingBlooded

Comment: @VikingBlooded I added a few changes to my code but I still get some errors...

Comment: var_dump out your final arrays and post them so we can see what you're getting.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I posted the var_dump results. Thank you so much for your help!